# How use history command in bash script in interactive shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I want create command log, and for this I use the history file. history file working in bash script when shebang is `#!/bin/bash -i` (interactive shell) and need sync `~/.bash_history` and history (in all of the session), for this use `history -a` in PROMPT_COMMAND.

finally, this is my command for find last command in history:

```
history | cut -c 8- | tail -1 >> ~/commandlog
```

and this command correct working in terminal but when used that in bash script, all of lines from script added to `history` and `~/.bash_history`.

**I don't want bash script lines add to history**

[My script lines when I enter a history command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cx8E0.png)

Comment: Each interpreter has its own history. When you run a shell, it runs in its own interpreter, not the interpreter of the interactive shell you started it from, so how would it know that other unrelated shell process's history?

Comment: It sounds like you should be writing a shell _function_, and not a script at all.